# CSS inlining in a Rails app: performance issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I need to send a bunch of transactional emails. Each of them is a bit different so I can't "cache" them between users.

I am using [Roadie](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) to inline CSS. It works fine except that it takes a lot of time and CPU power for every email, and my servers struggle.

I tried to use CachedProviders but it does not make a real difference (I think the problem is the inlining process itself).

Are there solutions to optimise this process?

Comment: are you doing the processing in a background job of some sort?

Comment: Yes. It's triggered by Cron as a background process. Thing is the CSS is fairly complex. I did not anticipate it would require that much ressources to inline. Unless I am missing some optimisation tricks.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others: what ended up working for us was to refactor our CSSs and remove all the CSS files/rules that were not used for the emails.

You might wonder why we had such "unused" CSS, but it's just that we were sharing  some CSSs with our main site to keep the code simple and clean. Even if specific rules were not used, the inlining process had to go through them.

By doing this we divided the rendering time by 5 in our specific case.